# Javascript Animation - Why Am I Unable to Scroll Now (in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, bonsaijs

I'm playing around with the bonsai.js library, and I added a big `stage` to the hero section of my site.  However, in Chrome, when the mouse is over the `stage` (between the tagline and blue button outline), I am unable to scroll down or up. In Firefox and Safari I am still able to scroll.  Why is Chrome acting up?

Site:  http://cainternet.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the bonsai.js library, but probably it is, because the bonsai.js library uses the wheel event and stops it from bubbling in a way, that it only affects chrome. Check the web for "Event Bubbling" for about this topic and check the event usage in your bonsai lib.

Comment: Thanks for your hep Xeed.  I couldn't figure out how to get scrolling back  But, no worry, I just discovered Adobe Edge.  And it is incredible.  Especially since I have a deep After Effects background.  I recommend everyone check out Adobe Edge.